# Oracle Insert Stmt with select stmt

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, toad

I am sitting working with Toad for oracle and trying to insert new records in table1 based on values from another table table2.

This is what I have wrote

```
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT person_name, person_role
       FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
       WHERE     t1.person_role = 'basic'
            AND sl.person_role IN
            ('end_user', 'service', 'owner')
```

But this gives me a read exclamation mark, when holding my mouse over it, this is what is shown: [Error Message](//imgur.com/QdNwwyP)

I am unsure what it is, that goes wrong here?

Comment: did you try to execute your insert statement? If it is wrong, you always can do rollback

Comment: @Tatiana : See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So I am just going to go into hiding :$

I had some insert stmt's above and apparently it can not ignore them,
so ctrl+B (Comment Block) the 3x select stmt's with union.

That made it work.

Comment: If you make sure you terminate each sql statement with a semi-colon, then "Execute Statement at cursor" will recognise that the statement is limited to the specifict sql statement at the cursor, rather than all of the statements since the previous semi-colon. Alternatively, you can highlight the statement you wish to run and then click on the button (or F9).